# Method does not getting called in ViewModel - MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have two Views :`MainView` and `ProfileView`.

User sets up `Age` property in the `ProfileView` and click on the previous arrow button (PreviousDialog bind) in order to go `MainView` to update `Age` property via `Messaging` protocol.

The following implementation in the `ProfileViewModel` does not call `NotifyUpdate` method when user click on the previous arrow button. I wonder what I am missing or doing wrong?

**ProfileViewModel.cs**

```
public ICommand PreviousDialog
{
   get
   {
       NotifyUpdate();
       return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>());
    }
}

// the following method does not get called 
private void NotifyUpdate()
{
    var message = new CustomMessage(this, Age);
    var messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
    messenger.Publish(message);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your press the `previous arrow button`, the `getter` of the `ICommand` property is not invoked. What happens instead is the [Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.execute(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `ICommand` is called, which calls the `delegate` you provided to the `MvxCommand`...`ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>()`.

If you want `NotifyUpdate` to get called when the `previous arrow button` is clicked, you should put the `NotifyUpdate` call into a separate method along with `ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>()` and pass that method into the `MvxCommand`....something like this:

```
public ICommand PreviousDialog
{
   get
   {
       return new MvxCommand(() => NotifyAndNavigate());
   }
}

private void NotifyAndNavigate()
{
    NotifyUpdate();
    ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: Baiscally right, you dont need to make a seperate method for it though. Just use new MvxCommand(()=> { NotifyUpdate();
    ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>();});